# Why can't humans use dietary citric or acetic acid as a primary source of energy?

Tags: metabolism, organs

As the Krebs cycle is involved with the conversion of food in to citric acid, why can't eating citric acid be used as a temporary primary source of energy - in place of fat/carbohydrate/protein?? It seems like a waste of energy to convert food into citric acid if there is freely available citric acid in your diet why wouldn't that preferentially be used for energy - as it would skip a lot of steps and therefore be more efficient. And what about drinking acetic acid for similar benefits, as "it is changed to citric acid by combining with oxaloacetic acid with the help of CoEnzyme A and ATP".

Comment: how do you get citric acid in nature?

Comment: I order it online via amazon. Citric acid. ;-)
Or I can find it in lemons too.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that you would need 100kg of citric acid a day for 2400 kcal diet http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/495309621

Comment: I think you mean 1kg. a day of citric acid, there are 2.5 calories per gram of citric acid. But the thing is I think that comparing equally to food calories is misleading, because if it were to be used for energy - it would be processed more efficiently than actual food which requires a lot of cellular energy to assimilate.

Comment: Please read what you have written: "If the krebs cycle is largely about converting food in to citric acid which then enters the krebs cycle." This is a conditional clause, rather than a sentence, but is obvious nonsense even if there were a main clause. How can a cycle do something to something if it is not already in the cycle in the first place? Please rewrite so it makes sense and in doing so spell Krebs with a capital K — it is the surname of Hans A Krebs who received the Nobel Prize for discovering the tricarboxylic acid cycle that bears his name.

Comment: Will do, David. There are various tiers to the Krebs and I should have been more specific.

Comment: If, as a non-scientist, you wish to post here about the Krebs Cycle you need first to learn about its place in energy metabolism. The "main" purpose of the Krebs cycle is not to produce citrate, but to oxidase acetate (from sugars or fats) to CO2, ultimately generating ATP. It is a cycle of reactions between metabolites, one of which is citrate, with entry from acetylCoA and oxaloacetate. No energy is used ("wasted") if a dietary metabolite has first to be converted to acetylCoA — quite the reverse. And your concept of efficiency bears no relation to scientific reality. I have voted to close.

Comment: Seems like a completely legitimate question to me. (there is no requirement to be knowledgeable in backgroun info for your question; just that you've done prior research, which is indicated sufficiently in the OP's post). I vote to keep open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't eating citric acid be used as a temporary primary source of energy - in place of fat/carbohydrate/protein?

No reason it can't. Citric Acid technically contains 2.5kcal/g -- which is almost half of protein/carbohydrates, almost a third of alcohol, and a fourth of fat.

So if someone needed 2500kcal/day, they'd need 1kg of straight Citric Acid. [There's about 47g/L of Citric Acid in citrus fruit juice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid) So if you wanted it all from "natural" sources you'd need to drink 21.3L of your favorite citrus juice, though that's a bit comical.

In terms of being more efficient since Citric Acid bypasses the first two enzymatic reactions,[the part where Citric Acid is processed into alpha-ketoglutarate via Isocitrate Dehydrogenase is the rate limiting step of the entire cycle](https://www.chem.uwec.edu/Webpapers2001/bauere/Pages/Isocitrate_dehyd/FullPagesISO/ISO_info.html). You wouldn't be saving any time by flooding your system just before the bottleneck.

Interesting question, though!

Comment: Thank you MCM! So this raises the question, how is it possible to raise the rate of the citric acid in to alpha-ketoglutarate via isocitrate dehydrogenase step?

Comment: In vivo? No idea. That would require either a lot more enzymes floating around waiting for substrate (not sure how you'd do that or maintain it), or a much more efficient enzyme -- something that could be theoretically done if you had a few hundred hours of world-class supercomputer access and the right research team, but also suffers from the "I don't know how to get it in you and keep it around" problem.

Chances are there's a better solution to whatever problem you're thinking this solves.

Comment: I'd like to try and research the idea more, I am not a scientist but would like to try form a better hypothesis and connect a few dots if possible, could you point me towards some easy to digest literature that could help a layman such as myself? Thanks!!

Comment: As far as getting citrate in to the blood stream, one idea would be a jello or an emulsion with lecithin, either with citric acid or sodium citrate, something that would slowly release it so as to optimize the transfer to the blood stream rather than the nullification by bicarbonate in the small intestine. I feel there must be a simple method to optimize the conversion of ingested acid in to cellular energy.

Comment: Another delivery idea would just be to slowly sip a citrate drink continuously throughout the day.

Comment: @ol_matty_man - I'm afraid I don't have some literature suggestions, as I don't fully understand what you wish to do. Basic metabolic processes are pretty well described via Wikipedia, and I'd suggest starting there if you're not familiar with the language. And, as I said, the problem is NOT the citrate -- it's the step going from citrate to alpha-ketoglutarate. That's the limiting step, and the bottleneck in the Krebs cycle.

Comment: Thank you. What I was trying to get at is, I think most of the citrate calories do not make it to the bloodstream, I think they are urinated out for the most part, so I was saying perhaps a way to deliver more citrate calories to the mitochondria would be to ingest citrate at a steady rate instead of all at once. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @ol_matty_man - About 95% of the citric acid we ingest goes through a metabolic process in our bodies. Unless you ingest an unusually high amount, the majority of what you eat/drink is used and not directly urinated out. That said, I still think you fail to see the problem: Getting citric acid into our bloodstream is easy. Getting more energy after doing so isn't. It is not the amount of citrate that's the problem, but the rate at which it is processed. Like a road with a stop light, the thing that determines traffic speed isn't the number of cars (the citrate), it's the stop light (enzyme).

Comment: thank you @MCM - I had read conflicting information about citric acid here: https://www.livestrong.com/article/327212-what-products-contain-citric-acid/ where it said most is urinated out.

Comment: one last thing. Is there a chance that on an extramitochondrial level that more citrate or acetate consumption can increase the output of acetyl-coa which then enters the cytoplasm, therefore providing more energy than eating equivalent calories without citric acid??

Comment: @ol_matty_man - No, in fact it's the opposite. Citrate is an inhibitor of one of the enzymes in glycolysis.

Comment: @MCM `About 95% of the citric acid we ingest goes through a metabolic process in our bodies...` And that's **only** if you don't "purposefully" ingest a high amount like the OP is suggesting! Think about it -- how would you even metabolize "excess dietary citrate" anyway? Cytosolic citrate lyase would split it into OAA and **cytosolic** acetyl-CoA, the latter of which is a substrate for fatty acid synthesis. So you would have to "synthesize" a bunch of fats just to burn them off later? A very impractical proposition!

Comment: Not only impractical, but those processes cannot even simultaneously occur *in the same cell* for that matter either -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_synthesis#Animals_cannot_resynthesize_carbohydrates_from_fatty_acids . So, chances are, all that "excess" citrate (from the OP) is simply just going to be excreted out of your system -- with no "metabolism" to speak of! (Unless you're claiming the body can somehow "metabolize" *cytosolic* acetyl-CoA, or "somehow" run the [citrate-malate shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrate%E2%80%93malate_shuttle) *in reverse*!)...